# Como passar uma lista montada em JSP e percorrê-la em uma função JS extraindo seus valores?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Tenho uma página jsp de um código legado. Um pedaço dela é o seguinte:

```
<form name="frm_pedido" method="post" action='<%=(flgPrimeiroPedido ? "/pedidoConfirmaEndereco.jsp" : "finaliza_pedido.jsp")%>' onsubmit="javascript: return false;">
    <input type="hidden" name="sem_inter2" value="<%=erro2%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="list_sem_inter2" value="<%=areasFuncionaisSemInter%>">
</form>
```

Essa variável `areasFuncionaisSemInter` é um Java `ArrayList` de `Strings`. O problema é que ao clicar em um botão na página, preciso passar essa lista para uma função JS e extrair seus valores. A função chamada ao clicar no botão é a `VerificaInter()`. Tentei o seguinte:

```
function VerificaInter() {

   if(document.frm_pedido.sem_inter2.value == 'true') {
      var iterator = document.frm_pedido.list_sem_inter2.values(); 
      alert('Os valores da lista sao:\n');
      iterator; // nao funcionou dessa forma...
      // logica pra iterar na lista e exibir os valores
      return false;
   }
   else {
      return true;
   }

}
```

Essa variável `iterator` não funcionou dessa forma e eu não consegui iterar sobre a lista e extrair seus valores. O que estou fazendo errado e como poderia realizar essa operação?

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que o seu hidden "list_sem_inter2" esteja retornando a lista neste formato:

```
<input type="hidden" name="list_sem_inter2" value="[P1, P2, P3]">
```

Seu JS vai receber está lista como uma String, então basta fazer:

```
var lista = document.frm_pedido.list_sem_inter2.value.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",");
alert('Os valores da lista sao: '+lista.length);
let iterator;
for(let i=0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    iterator = lista[i];
    alert(iterator);
}
return false;
```